# Decide with proof if the groups are isomorphic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Decide with proof if the groups are isomorphic.

$(a)\quad (\mathbb Z, +)$
$(b)\quad (3\mathbb Z, +)$
$(c) \quad$ The additive group of the rational numbers.

I've just done questions of the form groups "$C_2\times C_2$" etc but not really sure how to go about this.

Thank you

Comment: You'll have to rewrite using $\LaTeX$.  I can't understand it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\mathbb Z \cong 3\mathbb Z$$ under the isomorphism $\phi: \mathbb Z \to 3\mathbb Z$. Note, it is good to know that both $3\mathbb Z = \langle 3\rangle $ and $\mathbb Z = \langle 1 \rangle$ are cyclic groups of infinite order. And every infinite cyclic group is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$.

However, no single element generates all of $(\mathbb Q, +)$ (this is a good exercise to prove) and hence the additive group of the rationals is **not cyclic**, unlike the first two groups.

Any isomorphism between groups must preserve the groups' *structural properties*. Being cyclic is a structural property of a group.

Hence, $(\mathbb Q, +)$ is not isomorphic to either of the other groups.

Comment: I knew Z and 3Z are isomorphic, but how would I prove it?

Comment: You can simply use, as your proposed isomorphism, for $z \in \mathbb Z$, $\;\phi(z) = 3z$. Then show that it is bijective, and that it satisfies $\phi(z_1+z_2) = \phi(z_1) + \phi(z_2)$.

Comment: this is probably really stupid but how would i do that? i have real trouble doing things like that for, like, an infinite set, if that makes sense.

Comment: am i correct to say that;
ϕ(z1+z2)=3z1+3z2, and ϕ(z1)+ϕ(z2)=3z1+3z2 hence ϕ(z1+z2)=ϕ(z1)+ϕ(z2)

Comment: Almost, but Not quite. $\phi(z_1 + z_2) = 3(z_1 + z_2) = 3z_1 + 3z_2 = \phi(z_1) + \phi(z_2).$

Comment: how would i prove it is bijective?

Comment: no, sorry? what is that?

Comment: @amWhy: very nice discourse +1

Comment: @amWhy: you hit the target by a very simple effective solution+1

Answer (score 1):

The equation $ny=1$ in which $n\in\mathbb N$ has a solution in $(\mathbb Q,+)$ but it dos not have any in $(\mathbb Z,+)$.

Comment: So this shows that there is no isomorphisms between them that sends $1$ to $1$. I guess at least this leaves something for the OP to do themselves.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: In fact, I wanted to use the definition of "divisibility" for the rational numbers. However, other approaches are more simpler.

Comment: @amWhy: Good Amy. Thanks. However so slow on the site. :-)

Comment: $\ddot\smile$ Glad to hear! (Yes, it's been rather slow here!)

Comment: For the sake of rigour : $n \in \mathbb N \setminus \{0,1\}$.

Comment: @Pece: If we set $n=0$ then $n\notin\mathbb N$. But for $n=1$, yes you're right. :)

Comment: @B.S. You clearly not have the same definition of $\mathbb N$ than me. I want $\mathbb N$ to me a monoid, not just a semi-group. But I'm french and I know that conventions might change from one country to another.

Answer (score 0):

The additive groups $\mathbb{Z}$ and $3\mathbb{Z}$ are isomorphic via $z\mapsto 3z$.  The additive group of rationals is not, since it does not have a single generator.